# How to remove all controller names from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have multiple controllers in a Codeigniter project. I need to hide these controller names. For eg: I have two controller, home and school. Each school have their own page which includes about,gallery,contact etc. and url should be http://www.sitename.com/schoolname.  I hide home controller using routes.php. 
    $route['(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
But it shows error in school controller. Please help me..... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that a controller name is absolutely required.

In `routes.php` first define default controller to be `home` (when user accesses homepage sitename.com)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Then you create the rule that any other page should be redirected to `school` controller:

```
$route['.*'] = 'school';
```

Now the `home.php` controller will look like this:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function Index()
    {
        echo "This is the homepage";
    }

}
```

And in the `school.php` controller you have to manually get the name of the school from requested URL:

```
class School extends CI_Controller {

    public function _remap()
    {
        echo "User requested school: " . $this->uri->segment(1);
    }

}
```

Why use `_remap` method? Because it will be called everytime regardless of what's in URL or routing.

From [the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?#remapping-method-calls):

> If your controller contains a method named _remap(), it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $route['anything you want/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
```

controller name is required so set it with any name you want